# unable to receive success message from php to Ajax, jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with jQuery/Ajax where I need php to send me success, error message upon the status of form receiving. I have done a bit of googling but I am still unable to receive any message. I am using json_encode.

JS code:

```
$(function()

 {
 $("#logInBtn").click(function(e) 
 {
    var array = [];

    var userName = $("#logIn").val();
    var passWrd = $("#password").val();
    var flag = false;

    alert("Log In alert");

    if(userName == '' || passWrd == '')
    {
        alert("Username or password cannot be empty");
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        array.push(userName);
        array.push(passWrd);

        alert(array);
        flag = true;
    }

    if(flag == true)
    {
        alert("going for ajax");
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/login.php",
            data:
            {
                userName: array[0],
                passWrd: array[1],
            },
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(suc){
                alert("suc");
         alert(suc);   
                console.log(suc);
            },
            error: function(err)
            {
            alert("err");
            alert(err);
            console.log(err);
        }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("form error");
    }
        alert("final check here");
});
    }
    else
    {
        alert("form error");
    }
        alert("final check here");
});
}
);
```

php code:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT');

// The JSON standard MIME header.
header('Content-type: application/json');
     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
     mysql_select_db("monkey",$con);


$name = $_POST['userName'];
$pass = $_POST['passWrd'];


$query="INSERT INTO logInCheker(login,password) VALUES('$name','$pass');";


   if(mysql_query($query))
   {
       $response_array['status'] = 'success'; 
       echo json_encode($response_array);
   }
else
{
   $response_array['status'] = 'error'; 
   echo json_encode($response_array);

}


?>
```

[PS: Both JS and php code is dummy, especially the php code. I am not using this in the server side. ]
Thanks in advance.

Update:
The DB is updating informing. Each time, I hit login button, DB gets one row of data but my jQuery is saying it has hit in the error function. Here is the object i have received.

[image]

Comment: Are you preventing clicking the login button from submitting any forms or changing the url? you don't appear to be.

Comment: Can you tell what are you receiving, where is the problem ?

Comment: @Trim, I am receiving data in the php file but my jQuery is throwing error message. I have put an alert in error and success function. Each time, the alert of error function is getting hit.

Comment: @Trim, I have updated it with the error function aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following header solved the problem

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Apology as there were little confusion in the question as well as my bad english..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with your ajax request, try something like this:

```
$.ajax({                
    ...
    ...
    ...
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Also, you should be using [Prepared Statements in PDO](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for all DB interactions.

Comment: This was my previous code. I deleted the error part to check if it works when there is only success block.. I have updated the code with the error message now

Answer (score -1):

check the console.
Your php script is not a json for this reason:

```
echo $name;
echo "Donkey";
```

try remove this echos.

Comment: Why was this down voted? This seems correct to me. Since in his ajax he specified the type JSON then if the parse fails, according to the jquery documentation, success() will not be called.

Comment: This was not in my actual file. This is for some debugging in server side.